# Unable to pass props to child component

Tags: react-native, axios

I have a component that is fetching data on mounting and passing it to its child component that has table to iterate that data. In my parent component:

```
state={
    dataSales: [],
}


componentDidMount(){


        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-access-token',
            'x-access-token': this.state.id
        }

        axios.post('http://b******************OEMLevel2', {
            oem:'all'
        }, 
        {headers: headers})
        .then((res) => {

            let sample = res.data.data[0]

              this.setState({

                dataSales: sample
            })

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });

    }

   render() {
    console.log(this.state.dataSales)
    return (
        <View>


                {this.state.dataSales ? <Table oeminfo={this.state.dataSales}/> : null}


        </View>
    )
}
```

the format of my data received is :

[image]

In my child component:

```
export default class Table extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-around'}}>

                    <View><Text>Group</Text></View>
                    <View><Text>Total Sales</Text></View>
                    <View><Text>Percentage Sales</Text></View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

The console in child component gives empty array as:`{oeminfo: Array(0)}`

Please help to rectify the problem.

Comment: whats the response you are getting when you console log res.data

Comment: The one that is shown in image attached

Comment: are you getting it as an object ?

Comment: Yes.  It is array of objects, I guess

Comment: which array you are trying to store in the state

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in the question. My parent component and child component with the code. It is pretty clear to understand,

Comment: Have you checked that res.data.data[0] is properly set in this.state.dataSales ?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Yes. It is setting the state properly. I have added the console check for it inside render() method

Comment: try changing {this.state.dataSales ? <Table oeminfo={this.state.dataSales}/> : null} 
to {this.state.dataSales.length>0 ? <Table oeminfo={this.state.dataSales}/> : null}

Comment: I tried this already. But still no prop is getting passed to the child component.

Comment: just try changing componentdidmount to componentwillmount in your parent comp

Comment: this is a very common misunderstanding when working with data coming from ajax requests. At first this.state.dataSales is an empty array, so when the Table component is mounted and the componentDidMount function correctly logs this as an empty array. Note that the componentDidMount function will only be called once. So when the axios request returns the results and correctly updates the dataSales, you won't see any updated log. Try putting the console log in another lifecycle function such as componentDidUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are initializing the this.state.dataSales as an empty string "" ?

The problem may be that the this.state.dataSales?true:false condition is returning true and when the new props are received it wont update the child component

Comment: Yes I have initialized my state as an empty array. I am editing my code for reference.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I am not able to understand what you suggested.

Comment: If at first render the variable this.state.dataSales is [] the condition this.state.dataSales return true. You have to change it and see if the array is filled with something like ` {this.state.dataSales.length>0 ? <Table oeminfo={this.state.dataSales}/> : null}`

Comment: I tried this already. But still no prop is getting passed to the child component. Console from child is empty.

Comment: Do you see the response in the child props inside the componentDidUpdate function?

Comment: Yes I checked it. It says undefined.

Comment: Is it possible that state:{var1: value} is getting called in every render? can you try to initialize this.state inside the parent constructor? Or you just wrote it like that for the question?

Comment: Tried. Still no luck. I did `this.state={ dataSales :[] }`, still undefined.

Comment: Cant seem to recreate the problem in a new project. What version of react-native are you using?

Comment: for React 16.8.3, React-Native 0.59.9